# How do I access the information stored in my Game Center on my iPad?

Tags: ipad

I have a game linked to my Game Center and I need to get the login information for that game since I don’t seem to recall it. However I can’t open the Game Center. It’s not on the screen, it’s only in the settings and it won’t show me the information from there. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with “login information”?